# Functions from the output of Solve

Tags: functions, rule, output

The output of the equation

```
Solve[f[x] - x^2 == 0, f[x]]
```

is:

```
{{f[x] -> x^2}}
```

I would like the output to be

```
{f -> Function[x, x^2]}
```

In this way I can evaluate, for example,

```
f'[x] /. Out[2]
```

with the desired result,

```
2x
```

Can this be done?   Of course I have many equations
of this form, and far longer...  Thanks, Max

Comment: `Solve[f[x] - x^2 == 0, f[x]][[1]] /. Rule[func_, expr_] :> Rule[Head[func], (Function @@ {List @@ func, expr})]`

Comment: That was quick. Thank you Bob.

Comment: There's an internal function that changes solutions to functions for `DSolve`: ``DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[{{f[x] -> x^2}}]``

Comment: Thanks Michael. *Very* useful command too. Max

Answer (score 3):

Use the resource function [SolutionRulesToFunctions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SolutionRulesToFunctions/):

```
First@ResourceFunction["SolutionRulesToFunctions"][Solve[f[x] - x^2 == 0, f[x]]]

(*{f -> Function[{x}, x^2]}*)
```

Comment: I did not know about the ResourceFunction site!  Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've added a hyperlink. Please see the update. :-)